# ASP.NET WebAPI how to keep a state variable when user is authenticated

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a `ASP.NET WebAPI` project that servers `json` data to my mobile application.

On each mobile request to my Api I send http headers with the user sessionid so I can validate that request on server side.

So if my mobile application request for 10 json data catalogs, each request will have to validate if the sessionid is valid in order to return the data.

> My question is if its possible to save the state on server (like a traditional http session) so I can save round trips to my DB each time to validate the user sessionid.

I used to have `<authentication mode="None">` in my `web.config` file and had a filter on each controllers method that Validate the user sessionId. Inside my filter I used to have:

```
  ....
 if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return;
  ....
```

And that did the trick but now I was forced to add a Razor website in my WebAPI project so I had to change my authetnication mode to:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: FormsAuthentication sets `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, is this enough? Or is there some other state you're asking about?

Comment: Right now with auth=Forms I always get IsAuthenticated = true if the user logs into the portal, then if he tries to log into the other application says still IsAuthenticated = true

Comment: Well, forms-auth sets a cookie, and will recognize that cookie on every request and authenticate the user. Is this not what you want?

Comment: The problem is that for a 100% Rest API thats not correct right? Because WebAPI cant store cookies on server side neither sessions

Comment: Cookies are part of the request (just not part of the querystrings/post-data, but headers) and wont store anything server-side.